# Count number of rows matching multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, countif

I'm working with two Excel workbooks. The first one contains this table:

[image: this table]

The other contains this one:

[image: this one]

Is it possible with VBA, for each week, to count the number of rows matching three specific criteria (**first criteria**, **second criteria** and **code**) and put that value into the correct cell?

For example: count for week No.1 the number of rows with:

- first criteria = DELETE
- second criteria = LOCAL
- code = 46593

And then put that value into cell C4?

Comment: Is there a requirement to use VBA?  Have you looked at [COUNTIFS](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function)?

Comment: I have looked at COUNTIFS and the problem is that the second table's data will change over time. I need to be able to link the VBA code to a button so that I'll be able to get the correct count. Unfortunately, I have no other choice than using VBA

Comment: If you use named ranges or just whole column references, there would be no need for a button.  The results would automatically update as the data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `COUNTIFS`.

This formula must be put in cell `C3` and can be copied to the whole table:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$B:$B,$A3,Sheet2!$D:$D,$B3,Sheet2!$A:$A,C$2,Sheet2!$C:$C,46593)
```

---

However, since you want your data to be updated automatically, I found that *array* formulas work around this issue. Array formulas are entered not with usual <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=SUM(IF(('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$1000=$A3)*
        ('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet2'!$D$2:$D$1000=$B3)*
        ('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$1000=C$2)*
        ('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet2'!$C$2:$C$1000=46593),1,0))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with VBA ? The 2nd workbook's data will change over time and I've been asked to link the VBA code to a button so that the user will be able to update the count if necessary.

Comment: In VBA you can reach `COUNTIFS` using `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`

Comment: This is perfect ! Thank you very much !